# Getting issue in Intellij with log4j log file format

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

I was trying to generate log file in Intellij using Log4j2. I made properties file for Log4j2 and configured it in the base class of my framework. My logs are getting generated in my project root directory without any issue. But when I am opening th log file then Intellij is showing me an error for Log format so can anyone help me to resolve this issue of Intellij.

Here is my log4j2.properties file:-

```
//name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.append=true

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.framework
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Here are my console logs :-

```
Testing started at 4:09 PM ...
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/java/com/framework/features -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=58681:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/test-classes:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/classes:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/github/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.8.1/webdrivermanager-3.8.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/1.0.0/jarchivelib-1.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.14.3/testng-6.14.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.72/jcommander-1.72.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-java/6.1.2/cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-core/6.1.2/cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin/6.1.2/cucumber-gherkin-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin-messages/6.1.2/cucumber-gherkin-messages-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/messages/12.1.1/messages-12.1.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/tag-expressions/3.0.0/tag-expressions-3.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/10.2.1/cucumber-expressions-10.2.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/datatable/3.3.1/datatable-3.3.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-plugin/6.1.2/cucumber-plugin-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/docstring/6.1.2/docstring-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/html-formatter/6.0.3/html-formatter-6.0.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/net/masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.3.0/cucumber-reporting-5.3.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.1/jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.1/jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.1/jackson-core-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.10.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-engine-core/2.1/velocity-engine-core-2.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.5/joda-time-2.10.5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.3.0/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/20191001.1/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-20191001.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-testng/6.1.2/cucumber-testng-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59/selenium-api-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.141.59/selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/3.141.59/selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.141.59/selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/3.141.59/selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-opera-driver/3.141.59/selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.141.59/selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/3.141.59/selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/3.141.59/selenium-support-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.15/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/25.0-jre/guava-25.0-jre.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.0.0/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.11.0/okhttp-3.11.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter4.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter3.jar io.cucumber.core.cli.Main --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --name ^To test search functionality with blank submit$ --glue com.framework.utils --glue com.framework.stepDef /Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/java/com/framework/features/Home.feature
Invoking new Webdriver instance
[INFO ] 2020-08-07 16:09:32.230 [main] BaseSetup - New Webdriver instance invoked
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 27490
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 07, 2020 4:09:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
The page title verified is My Store
The validation for mainbanner on homepage has been completed
The validation for search field on homepage has been completed
Closing existing Webdriver instance
[INFO ] 2020-08-07 16:09:41.853 [main] BaseSetup - Webdriver instance closed

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
5 Steps (5 passed)
0m10.408s



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my Baseclass file where I am using the log manager and calling the logs:-

```
package com.framework.utils;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseSetup {

    protected static WebDriver driver=null;
    protected static PropertiesReader read;
    protected static Logger logger;

    @Before
    public void pre_setup(){
        read=new PropertiesReader();
        logger= LogManager.getLogger(BaseSetup.class.getName());
    }

    public static WebDriver webdriverSetup(){

        if (driver==null){
            System.out.println("Invoking new Webdriver instance");
            logger.info("New Webdriver instance invoked");
            if(read.getBrowsername().equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
                driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
            }

            else if (read.getBrowsername().equalsIgnoreCase("safari")) {
                driver=new SafariDriver();
            }
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    @After
    public void teardown(){
        if (driver!=null){
            System.out.println("Closing existing Webdriver instance");
            logger.info("Webdriver instance closed");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
            driver=null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error which I am facing in Intellij in log file for the log format:-

[image]

Comment: `Here is the error which I am facing in Intellij in log file for the log format` When plugin do you use any 3rd plugin for viewing the logs? Looks like it needs to be configured accordingly.

Comment: @Andrey I am using Ideolog plugin which is default plugin to view log files in Intellij I don't have idea about log format configuration which is needed for my plugin so can you help me out in finding out the appropriate configuration for that plugin

Comment: Check the plugin's documentation: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/wiki/Custom-Log-Formats about custom log format.

Comment: I checked the plugin configuration for log format it has not defined clearly which kinds of formats it supports and hw we are going to define it

Comment: Hi @keshavdwivedi, try %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} (comma separator instead of point for the nanoseconds).

Comment: Hi @hce it worked like a charm, The error thrown by Intellij was immediately gone Thanks a lot Really appreciate your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per advice of @hce I went of in configuration settings for Log format of ideolog and configured a new pattern which is `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} and immediately after enabling it, The error thrown by Intellij was gone.
Hence error was solved after adding this pattern in log format of Ideolog.